# Magento 2 : Add custom products to shopping cart price rule

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I set a custom shopping cart price rule with this code

```
 $rule
        ->setName('Loyalty card')
        ->setDescription('Loyalty card')
        ->setFromDate('2016-11-15')
        ->setToDate(NULL)
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(null)//unlimited
        ->setUsesPerCustomer(null)//unlimited
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array($regularCustomerGroup->getId()))
        ->setCustomerGroupId($regularCustomerGroup->getId())
        ->setIsActive('1')
        ->setSortOrder('1')
        ->setCouponType('2')
        ->setSimpleAction('by_percent')
        ->setDiscountAmount(20)
        ->setDiscountStep('0')
        ->setSimpleFreeShipping('0')
        ->setApplyToShipping('0')
        ->setTimesUsed('0')
        ->setUseAutoGeneration('1')
        ->setIsRss('0')
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
        ->setCouponCode(NULL);

    $rule->getResource()->save($rule);
```

Now I need to add custom products to this rule using cron. How can I add an array of custome, previously selected products to this with some sort of method like `setProductIds()` or something of that kind?

Thank you!